# Integration using only two rules and by parts.

Tags: calculus

I need to integrate a few fractions of form $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ where ${p(x)}$ is a polynomial of degree 1 or and $q(x)$ being a polynomial of degree 2 only using integration by parts and following two rules:

$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\, dx = \ln| f(x)|+C$$

$$\int \frac{a}{a^2+x^2}\, dx = \arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C$$

Would someone be able to integrate $\frac{3x-1}{x^2-2x+5}$ as an example for me using only these three ways? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wheat happens when you compete the square in the denominator?

Comment: Well, what then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int{{3x-1}\over{x^2-2x+5}}dx=\int{{3(x-1)+2}\over{(x-1)^2+4}}dx=\int{{3(x-1)}\over{(x-1)^2+4}}dx+\int{{2}\over{(x-1)^2+4}}dx={{3\over 2}\ln((x-1)^2+4){}}+\arctan\left({{x-1}\over 2}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\frac{3x-1}{x^2-2x+5}$$

$$\int\frac{ 2x-2}{(x-1)^2+4}+\int\frac{ x+1}{(x-1)^2+4}$$

$$\int\frac{( 2x-2)dx}{(x-1)^2+4}+\int\frac{ (z+2)dz}{z^2+4}$$

$$I=\frac 3 2\int\frac{ (2z)dz}{z^2+4}+\int\frac{ 2dz}{z^2+4}$$

Where $z=x-1$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{3x-1}{x^2-2x+5}= 3\frac {(x-1)}{(x-1)^2+4}+\frac{2}{(x-1)^2+4}  $$

Now you can get your result.